# Правильно ли стоят запятые? Есть ли тут уточнения?

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли расставлены запятые? Есть ли тут уточняющие обороты? И можно ли начинать предложение с чисел?

> 1. В тот же день точка Б2 располагалась на расстоянии 8.5 км от первой на обрывистом берегу высотой 20 м от уровня моря на Толстом мысу
>      Геленджикской бухты.
> 2. 20 октября точка Б1 располагалась на обрывистом берегу моря на высоте около 60 м западнее Голубой бухты.
> 3. 19 октября точка А1 располагалась непосредственно на берегу Голубой бухты на высоте 4 м (высота антенн) над уровнем воды.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я уточнений не углядела, и без запятых трудночитаемо. Как говаривали в редакциях, "а чего их плодить-то?"...

Числа (цифры) в начале предложения не возбраняются, но в художественной литературе используются числительные.

Вопрос Грамоте.ру:

> Здравствуйте! Можно ли начинать предложение с даты (например, "15
>   апреля 2011 г. состоялось собрание...") или номера съезда (например,
>   "IV съезд организации ... ") в научных исторических текстах.
>   Справочники не рекомендуют начинать предложение с цифры, но в
>   исторических трудах такое встречается сплошь и рядом. Как же все-таки
>   правильно?

**[Ответ справочной службы русского языка](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20267140)**

> Начинать предложение с даты (с цифры) можно.